# How to set Grid.DataTable column values to not editable using C# in SAP

Tags: c#, datatable, business-objects

I created a simple DataTable in SAP using C# and fill the table with a Query. Afterwards I can display the table without any problem. But the user can edit column values which is not nice. I can't find a way to make them not editable.

Is there a simple way do this like `oGrid.Datatable.Columns.readonly()...`?

I know in C# "DataGridView" you can do that.

Any SAP pros who can help me?  Thanks in advance!

My code can be seen below

```
            private SAPbouiCOM.Grid oGrid;
            ....
            //  Set the grid data
            oGrid = ((SAPbouiCOM.Grid)(oItem.Specific));

            oForm.DataSources.DataTables.Add("MyDataTable");
            oForm.DataSources.DataTables.Item(0).ExecuteQuery("....");
            oGrid.DataTable = oForm.DataSources.DataTables.Item("MyDataTable");
            GridCount = oGrid.DataTable.Rows.Count;
            //  Set columns size
            oGrid.Columns.Item(0).Width = 50;
            oGrid.Columns.Item(1).Width = 60;
            oGrid.Columns.Item(2).Width = 130;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was found out to be a very easy thing to do. But there's no way to just set the whole table to not editable. You have set each and every column to not editable like below.

```
oGrid.Columns.Item(0).Editable = false;
```